# How to set the servlet filter name when add a servlet filter in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I'm trying to use FilterRegistrationBean to register a Servlet filter in Spring Boot project, but I don't how to set a name for this filter, because i did't set the filter name, Spring will automatic give a name base on the class name of this filter. For example, the filter below will given a name "someFilter". **So how can I set a name for this filter?**

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    SomeFilter filter = new SomeFilter();

    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

registrationBean.setName() method can do the work, thx.

Comment: How about reading [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/RegistrationBean.html#setName-java.lang.String-)...

Comment: @M.Deinum  setName() method  works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your method name is your bean name : http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Answer (score 1):

**Not only** for filter, you can set name for **any** Spring bean like below.

```
@Bean(name="bean_name_which_i_want")
```